# Name of 3 dots to indicate a pause in speech

Tags: terminology, ellipses

Answers to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50559/using-ellipsis-to-indicate-a-pause-in-conversation) show that it is quite common to use the 'ellipsis' (three dots) in English writing to indicate a pause in speech for reasons of "confusion, insecurity, distress, or uncertainty".

I agree with this usage, but is it still appropriate to call the 3 dots an 'ellipsis' in this case?  I generally associate 'ellipsis' with omission; indeed, that's its [primary meaning](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ellipsis), with the reference to the typographical 3 dots being secondary.  Is there a better word or phrase to use to refer to the 3 dots being used to indicate a pause in speech (either real as in quotes, or abstract as in written prose)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better phrase to use to refer to the 3 dots being used to indicate a pause in speech is ***Suspension point***, as we can read on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_point):

> *The triple-dot punctuation mark is also called a **suspension point**,
>   points of ellipsis, periods of ellipsis, or colloquially, dot-dot-dot.*

However, [Collins English Dictionaries](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/suspension-point) defines *suspension point* as follow:

> ***Suspension point*** - mainly US one of a group of dots, usually three,
>   used in written material to indicate the omission of a word or words.
>   Compare ellipsis (sense 2)<sup>*</sup>.

So, perhaps, the better phrase may be **suspension points** (note the 's' at the end).

* *<sub>**Ellipsis** - Also called eclipsisomission of parts of a word or sentence printing a sequence of three dots (...) indicating an omission in text.</sub>*

Comment: When it is at the end of a sentence, a trailing off into silence, it is called *aposiopesis* . Example: "But I thought he was . . ."

Comment: @speedyGonzales I think you are correct. Why not answer the question? You are more correct than you realize, even! That term seems to be applicable anywhere in the sentence per the following "[Aposiopesis] can simulate the impression of a speaker so overwhelmed by emotions that he or she is unable to continue speaking. . . . It can also convey a certain pretended shyness toward obscene expressions or even an everyday casualness." (Andrea Grun-Oesterreich, "Aposiopesis." Encyclopedia of Rhetoric, ed. by Thomas O. Sloane. Oxford Univ. Press, 2001)

Comment: Carlo, you've misinterpreted what Collins says.  It says that each of the three dots is called a suspension point; that is, the name of each character is suspension point, as opposed to being a full stop, or "terminal point".  The set of three dots still is called an ellipsis.

Comment: @speedyGonzales, *[aposiopesis](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/aposiopesis)* is abrupt, rather than trailing, and indicated by dash (–) rather than dots (…).

Comment: @jwpat7 - I like your comment, but Wikipedia said (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_point): "The triple-dot punctuation mark is also called a suspension point, points of ellipsis, periods of ellipsis, or colloquially, dot-dot-dot." On the other hand, we can call the 3 dots you are referring **Suspension points** (note the letter "s" at the end)

Comment: The Wikipedia article seems to be citing [this typesetting manual](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=l_YJY3JalQgC&pg=PA73&dq=%22Suspension+point%22+words&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pGeCT_yOFsm90QXhydnwBg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwADge#v=onepage&q=%22Suspension%20point%22%20words&f=false), which I think is *wrong*. Periods, commas, semicolons, etc, are all (rarely) referred to as "suspension points", as @jwpay7 says. I think there is no significant recognition for the term specifically meaning the three-dot **elipsis**.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character U+2026 ('**…**') is [HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm).

Answer (score -3):

In scriptwriting, a pause in speech is parenthetically noted like this:

```
JACK
(shouting)
You think I can be bought?
(a beat)
A million dollars?
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_%28filmmaking%29), a **beat** "usually refers to a pause in dialogue [which] shows readers of the script that a moment passes without any character speaking."

Comment: That Wikipedia article clearly states in the header that references are missing, to corroborate the definition. The talk page on Wikipedia clarifies regarding the possible meaning of beat  `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Beat_(filmmaking)` and links here http://www.screenwriter-to-screenwriter.com/2009/06/what-technically-is-a-beat-in-a-screenplay/ which refutes the definition of beat in this  answer.

Comment: @FeralOink you may want to look up the definition of "refute" in a dictionary before you go around bloviating and downvoting. You misleadingly claim that the WP article states that "references are missing"; it does  not, but someone complained about the lack of _inline references_. Keep looking on the web and you will find plenty of pages that back me up, for example [here](http://scriptwritingsecrets.com/Parenthetical.htm) and [here](http://messageboard.donedealpro.com/boards/showthread.php?p=111385). [Offensive bits removed by mod.]

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: there is no need to take downvotes personally (we downvote the answer, not the answerer), and it is not really polite to offend other users, especially when they clearly explain the reasons for their downvotes. Anyway, the question clearly asks about the `...` sign, which is not called a beat (a term that is anyway restricted to filmmaking and possibly theater), therefore your answer is not replying to the OP's question.

Comment: @nico When some pseudonymous porcine stops by with a rude, factually incorrect critique you bet that I will respond in kind. Of course my answer is on point. It is telling the OP, step back and think whether you really must use the three dots to indicate a pause in speech. Because if not, `beat` would be one alternative to consider. I am not aware of any rule on this web site that says that our Answers must hew slavishly to the letter of a Question.

Comment: @Eugene Seidel: there is no such rule, everyone is free to answer as he or she wills. However if the community thinks that your answer is not replying to the question for whatever reason, whether you think it is fair or not, the answer will get downvoted. Rather than complaining it would be more proficuous to improve your answer. When I downvote an answer I try to explain why I did that so that the answerer can modify it (or not). Following that I can (or not) change my vote to a +1 or simply remove the -1. It is as simple as that, so no need to get upset for a -1.

Comment: "Proficuous", huh. I'm done here.

Comment: @Eugene Seidel: **Proficuous** (a.): Profitable; advantageous; useful.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel That is rude! Pseudonymous porcine? My comment was  NOT rude nor factually incorrect. I provided a reason for downvoting your answer, and noted (separately) that there was an alternative answer that correctly responded to the question!

Comment: Pro tips for you two geniuses: (1) Using adverbs like "clearly" does not accomplish what you think it accomplishes; in fact, it has the opposite effect. (2) Using 13-dollar words like "proficuous" does not make you look well-read; it makes you look like an effete snob.