# Using punctuation within a question to create a pause

Tags: punctuation, questions, em-dashes, indirect-question

Is it possible to create a long **pause** (confusion) in the following question.

*'**You're maybe** wondering how could that be. That she is considering running away?'*

Between '**be and that**', I was considering using an em-dash to create a prolonged pause, if possible.

fyi,
I believe that the first clause requires a period (indirect question).

Comment: Assuming that the narrator is talking to the reader ('you' being the reader), would it be possible to add an em-dash? I have changed the question in the question.

Comment: Maybe see also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63374/

Comment: I give you the modern master of punctuation, now deceased unfortunately: Tom Wolfe http://www.english.upenn.edu/~despey/wolfe.htm Study him. :)

Comment: @Lambie Tom Wolfe, and also Joan Didion, especially _The White Album._ For punctuation of dialogue especially, David Foster Wallace, _Infinite Jest_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A period already does suggest a pause. I wouldn't think that even an em dash would necessarily suggest a longer pause—although it's subjective how each person interprets the cadence of a sentence.

If you finish the first sentence with a question mark that will also indicate a pause—possibly one even longer than just a period:

> You maybe wondering how that could be? That she is considering to run away?

It's true that this turns it into a direct question. But it seems unidiomatic to me that these two sentences should mix indirect and direct questions in the first place.

If I think of hearing somebody keeping their voice level with the first sentence, and raising it with the second sentence, it doesn't sound right. (Unless a *shorter* pause is used.) But raising their voice after *each* sentence—or keeping it level—seems more appropriate:

> You're maybe wondering how this could be. That she is considering running away.

Note, too, that the second sentence is actually a sentence fragment rather than a fully independent clause—but that can be fine in fiction, informal writing, or dialogue.

As referenced in another comment, an ellipsis could also be used. But that's just a matter of style.

---

Still, in all possible answers to this, it will be a matter of style (and subjectivity) rather than anything certain.

Comment: Does *wondering* take a mark of interrogation at the end? How can (the first) *that* make a forward reference?

Comment: In the first sentence the *are* is elided. Also, I'm assuming the *that* is referring to something somebody said *previously*, so it's actually a backwards reference to content we don't have. (Like: *You what? With that?*) It's like one of those utterances in speech that doesn't correspond to  normal structure. Of course, this is really just speculation without knowing more about the source of the text.