# Comma Usage in "but if we do"

Tags: commas

Here's my sentence:

> I haven't played much Risk, but if we do, you can imagine what would
>   happen.

Is the above correct, or is one of the two sentences below correct?

> I haven't played much Risk, but, if we do, you can imagine what would
>   happen.
>
> I haven't played much Risk but, if we do, you can imagine what would
>   happen.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In that case, would it be the second one?

Comment: I would phrase it as a rhetorical question: _I haven't played much Risk, but can you imagine what would happen if we did?_ < or answering the question: >  _I haven't played much Risk, but you only imagine what would happen if we did play._

Answer (score 4):

Commas are written ways to (attempt to) record the intonation contour of a sentence; there are many [varieties of such contours](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50563/15299), with different pragmatic and semantic effects. The comma is a rather primitive way of doing it -- one binary on/off mark to represent all continuous variations in tone, volume, and rhythm. The basic comma rule is: [if you hear it, you write it](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/178994/15299). If you don't hear it, you don't write it.

But what are you sposta listen for? Basically, it's a [sine wave](https://www.google.com/search?q=sine%20wave). From the normal indicative `mid` tone to the `high` tone, then down to `low` and back to `mid` again, very fast, usually no more than two syllables. The comma is placed where the intonation happens. There is no pause in the sound stream, but it's often called a "pause" because it functions to separate constituents of the utterance.

The prototype intonation curve is the rhythm and melody of a list, as in counting:

- *... fifty-one, fifty-two, fifty-three, fifty-four, fifty-five, ...*

In the presenting sentence

- *I haven't played much Risk, but if we do, you can imagine what would happen.*

the first clause is a complete sentence and ends with full stop intonation. It should end with a semicolon instead of a comma in print; comma intonation is wrong here; it's a classic comma splice.

- *I haven't played much Risk; but if we do, you can imagine what would happen.*

And now why do we need a *but*? Simply putting these two clauses together without a conjunction tells the story better; *but* indicates surprise, but there is no surprise in this conclusion. And, with no *but*, the issue of over-commatizing the clause is averted.

- *I haven't played much Risk; if we do, you can imagine what would happen.*

After contrastive *do*, there's another issue. Some proform is needed beside *do*, since the subject has changed from *I* in the first clause to *we* in the next, so the VP deletion is not quite complete.
Better would be something like

- *I haven't played much Risk; if we do play it, you can imagine what would happen.*

Finally, *will* (contracted, naturally, to *what'll*) is better than *would* here; there's no need to invoke irrealis conditions repeatedly in a hypothetical clause -- it's already imaginary and can't get any more so.

- *I haven't played much Risk; if we do play it, you can imagine what'll  happen.*

Comment: "it's a classic comma splice" -- Can you explain why it's a comma splice when there _is_ a conjunction "but" after the comma? FWIW, I've seen many such examples in writing where two independent clauses are separated by a parenthetical dependent clause set off by commas.

Comment: The conditions you mention are grammatical, not phonological. As I said, the first clause ends with full-stop intonation, not comma intonation. That's why the semicolon is required - it's a full stop, phonologically and syntactically. That's what "comma splice" means -- substituting a comma for a full stop.

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed 'I haven't played much Risk. If we _do_ have a game, you can imagine what will happen.' shows statements that are not mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

According to [GrammarBook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp), only the second one is correct because of rules 3b and 4a together (connector, "but", and dependent clause, respectively).

I would also choose number two based on personal preference.

However, I think an argument could be made for the first one, too, in that it's just less pauses for a reader to make.

Meanwhile, I would definitely not use the third one.

As an aside, I would have said,

> I haven't played much Risk, but, if *I were to (play a lot of Risk)*, you *could* imagine what would happen.

because I would want to use [subjunctive](http://writingexplained.org/was-vs-were-difference) in this case.

What do you think?

Comment: Even less than 100 years ago commas on each side of that 'but' would have been almost compulsory. Now at least either is entirely optional, which indicates both are.

Comment: Hmmmm, @RobbieGoodwin, I half agree with your statement. I think the second comma depends on how much emphasis we the speaker would want to place on "but," but I think the comma before "but" is 99% compulsory. I'm having a difficult time reading the sentence without the pause that would be indicated by a comma. And you had been referring to the alternative sentence I had given, yes?

Comment: Thanks, Teacher… I wasn't singling out your sentence; I largely agree but it goes a long way from the original.

However if you look back at contemporary editions of, say, Dickens or Rider Haggard, HG Wells or even my own grand-father, let alone people like Lovecraft or Bulwer-Lytton, they seem to think commas are the be-all and end-all, particularly when they can squeeze in another '…, but, …' like yours or another  '…, and, …'

That was and remains a matter of choice and to me '…, but, …' always seems old-fashioned, if not archaic…

Comment: Heh, @RobbieGoodwin, I see. In that case, then I'm a little lost :O :D. Do you mean that you think that even the OP's sentences don't need any commas at all since if "either is entirely optional, [then] both are"? I guess I just don't think that either is "entirely optional"? Meanwhile, I understand what you mean about over-comma-ing, so I would be totally OK with just two (:O) commas :D.

Comment: I think any real rules are too subtle for sentences like that and in every-day English 'I haven't played much Risk but if we do, … ' as at least as likely as the others… which is not to say that any of them is wrong.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin In everyday English, I’d say even “I haven’t played much Risk but if we do you can imagine what will happen” is quite common. Not a style I’m personally very fond of (in fact, I heartily dislike it), but fairly common nonetheless.

Comment: Really, Janus? You could be entirely correct and where have you actually seen *I haven’t played much Risk but if we do you can imagine what will happen*, however commonly, please?

If you've simply heard it, how can you know what punctuation the speaker intended?